# redirect url A to url B

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I two domains.  domainA.co.uk and domainB.co.uk

domainA.co.uk is the main site.  this is where all the files are, including the htaccess file

domainB.co.uk is not hosted on the same server, but the DNS A record is pointing to the domainA.co.uk IP address.

Is it possible to redirect domainB.co.uk to domainA.co.uk/page?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long ago was the DNS change made?

Comment: probably about a month ago... should have propagated fully by now! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On domainB.co.uk pointing host enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domainA.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: +1 from me as well. I swear whenever I use [R=301] I'm told, "but I don't want my url to change." :)

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Thanks. Yes that is funny :) However in this case domains were different so I guessed `R` is needed here.

Comment: @anubhava .. but since domain B's DNS was pointing to domain A's server; I actually thought of this as how hosting companies setup an add-on domain (in the sub-dir of the primary domain). Well, "client is always right!" :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory of `domainA.co.uk`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It didn't work for me though.  The answer below did. Thanks

Comment: @magicspon, both the answers are correct. I just did an internal redirect (no [R=301]) because usually people prefer to keep the other domain name showing in the address bar.

Comment: Hello, Just tried it again, this time with Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews, but it still doesn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: @magicspon, it's okay. If you've already got it working, don't mess around with your setup any more.

Comment: I would prefer to be able to have domainB.co.uk/page as the url. This is what I have at the moment:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?hartconstructionanddesign\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://hartdesignandconstruction.co.uk/construction-design%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Actually, my code serves `domainB.co.uk/index.php` transparently (without external redirect) from `domainA.co.uk/page/index.php`. So, it's like domainB living out of a sub-dir `/page` of the main domainA. So, going to `domainB.co.uk/page` would give a 404 because the idea is to make the add-on domain appear as another top level domain.

Comment: I think I understand... .htaccess melts my brain a little! thanks anyway ;)